# Run Node.Js on localhost

Tags: node.js, sql-server, google-chrome, express

i created a node.js code that listen to sql server and access it database and im trying to run the code on browser using "http://localhost:1433/test" but it always giving men this[image]

this is my node.js code:

```
const uid = require('uuid');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sql = require('mssql');
const driver = require('msnodesqlv8');

const config = {
// multipleStatements: true, TO EXECUTE MORE THAN ONE QUERY IN ONE STATEMENT
//driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
server: 'MOSTAFA',
user: 'admin',
password: 'mostafabaron123@',
database: 'WholeSale',
options:{
 trustedConnection: true,
 useUTC: true,
}
};
const userExistCode = 200;
const buyerCreatedCode = 400;
const buyerNotCreatedCode = 401;
const sellerCreatedCode = 500;
const sellerNotCreatedCode = 501;
const connectionErrCode = 100;

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // accept JSON parms
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


// bueyer signup part
app.post('/buyerSignUp', function(req, res) {
var postData = req.body; // get post params
var userId = uid.v4();

sql.connect(config, (err)=>{
 if(err){
   console.log('not connected');
   return;
 }

var request = new sql.Request();

request.input('email', sql.VarChar(45), postData.email)
.input('password', sql.VarChar(45), postData.password)
.input('category', sql.VarChar(45), postData.category)
.query('select * from Buyer where email = @email and category = @category 
and password = @password'
, (err, recordSet)=>{
  if(recordSet.length == 1){
  res.status(userExistCode).send("Buyer already exists.");
 }else{
    new sql.Request()
    .input('buyerId', sql.VarChar(45), userId)
    .input('firstName', sql.VarChar(45), postData.firstName)
    .input('lastName', sql.VarChar(45), postData.lastName)
    .input('email', sql.VarChar(45), postData.email)
    .input('password', sql.VarChar(45), postData.password)
    .input('phoneNumber', sql.VarChar(45), postData.phoneNumber)
    .input('category', sql.VarChar(45), postData.category)
    .query('insert into Buyer(buyer_id, first_name, last_name, email, 
    password, phone_number, category) values(@buyerId, @firstName, 
    @lastName, @email, @password, @phoneNumber, @category)'
    , (err, recordSet)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
        if(recordSet.length == 1){
          res.status(buyerCreatedCode).send("Account Created as Buyer.");
        }else{
          res.status(buyerNotCreatedCode).send("Account not Created as 
 Buyer.");
        }
 });
 }
 });
 });
 });
 app.listen(1433, ()=>{
 console.log('server is running on 1433...');
 });
```

what i expect to see the messages if the user created or already existed.
anyone can explain why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure your express server is running (did you start it)?  Something is clearly wrong here, because you are trying to start express on port 1433 _and_ trying to connect to MSSQL on port 1433.  Both things can't be true.

Comment: i run this code on cmd and then i access it with localhost

Comment: this what gives me as output when i run it on cmd : "connected
server is listening on port 1433:"

Comment: i also test it on ARC and it gives me this: "The requested URL can't be reached
The service might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

The response status is empty. It means that the successful connection wasn't made. Check your request parameters."

Comment: What do you expect to see on `/test`?

Comment: My guess would be that your app isn't returning anything for a GET request. Does adding this help: `app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})`

Comment: show message if the data were added or not @joshlee

Comment: no man the same result.@JoshLee

Comment: @ElliotNelson why the both can't be true? can you explain more.

Comment: A port can only be listened to by 1 program at a time.  If program A is using a port, and program B tries to listen to it, it will raise an error.  Port 1433 is the default port for MSSQL, so the fact that express is even starting makes me suspect your database server isn't running.

Comment: (Normally, if you are running express, you would use the port 3000 or 4000 for the express server, and port 1433 for MSSQL.)  Of course once deployed to production, you would use the standard ports 80 (for HTTP) and 443 (for HTTPS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from reading your code, here is what I suspect is happening: you are starting up express and listening to port 1433. It does successfully call your listening callback and print the appropriate `console.log` statement, so we know it gets that far.

Then, you attempt to connect to your database. Your *database port* is also 1433, which we know is not correct (the database port cannot be the same as your express port, if it was, express would never have started). So your connection to the database fails.

The database connection callback checks for an error, then returns. This means you'll never see the "connected" `console.log` statement, and you'll never actually create the route for `/buyerSignup`. Basically, your app is running, but has no useful routes.

(I'm not sure what you even expect to see at the URL `/test` -- nothing in this code snippet shows you creating that route. But, you'll need to fix the issues above in any case.)

Comment: first i screenshot the wrong page sorry about that it supposed to be /buyerSignUp. second, i'm totally a beginner easy on me, so it's okay to use express in my app besides my server instance is MSSQLSERVER not SQLEXPRESS? and i thought that i only need the server port to connect to the database.@EilliotNelson

Comment: It helps to think of your application as a collection of components.  For example, you might have MSSQLSERVER (database) listening on port 1433, Redis (caching) listening on port 6793, and Express (application server) listening on port 4000.  In the browser, you'll connect to port 4000 (http://localhost:4000); behind the scenes, your application will connect to the database at port 1433 and your cache layer at port 6793.  But, each component does need its own dedicated port.